# Show value in hours, but store in minutes in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a column in database that stores value in minutes. I want to let user edit it, but enter value in hours. So I need to convert value from minutes to hours when I render form and convert it back when I save object. Form is used for editing the object, not creating.

Here is my solution:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    time_zone = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Time zone"),
                                 choices=[(tz, tz) for tz in pytz.common_timezones],
                                 default='Europe/Kiev',
                                 max_length=50)
    learning_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_("Learning time"), default=30, validators=[
        MinValueValidator(30),
        MaxValueValidator(480),
    ])

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('time_zone',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        initial_learning_time = kwargs.get('initial') and kwargs['initial'].get('learning_time')
        self.fields['learning_time'].initial = initial_learning_time or kwargs['instance'].learning_time / 60.0

    learning_time = forms.DecimalField(min_value=0.5, max_value=8, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'step': 0.5}),
                                       label=_("Daily learning time (hours)"))

    def save(self, commit=True):
        profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(commit)
        profile.learning_time = self.cleaned_data['learning_time'] * 60
        if commit:
            profile.save()
        return profile
```

Any better / simpler way?

Comment: Why not make a custom field to encapsulate the functionality? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-model-fields/

Comment: @Brandon, I store and use it everywhere in minutes, just want to provide an ability to define it in hours in this form, so custom field will complicate it a little.

Comment: How so? When you retrieve the property, it can be displayed in hours and stored in minutes in the DB. See here: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2327/ for an example of how to store a value as a decimal, but display it as several different widgets.